# how to create a "makefile" for c++?

Tags: unix, makefile

I usually work on visual c++ 2010 for creating console applications as programming problems. There is this submission which requires me to give the source for the file "Makefile" by some command in unix environment

all:
    g++ program.cc -o program

since i don't use unix and have never created a "makefile". I don't know how to make this submission. I have read about a makefile which is supposed to give the directions dependencies etc for compiling the program. I am using the header files iostream string and iterator in the program. i have tried the "all:" command . The bash returns command not found.

Can someone help me with this submission? The code is ready but the only thing stopping for submitting is this "makefile". please include the shell commands as well.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing newline and two tabs (yes, you read right, not spaces) after the `all:` line, something like this:

```
all:
        g++ helloworld.cc -o helloworld
```

To invoke make, type `make` in the directory with the Makefile. Dependencies on system headers are usually not considered, if your code has just one file, you can safely ignore that.

Comment: i will invoke make once i have created the makefile.. how do i do that?

Comment: pretty naive on this one.. how do i get the newline? i press enter after "all:" it says command not found.

Comment: Put the above code written by eudoxos into a file called `Makefile`. Then, once you have saved the file type `make` on the command line and then press enter(!). I encourage you to read this: http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/

Comment: The manual for Make, http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html is actually pretty easy reading, and should be really quick to skim for your immediate purposes. I encourage actually taking the effort, and learning how to better learn.